# MySQL row number query is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to return a row number column in MySQL and I've resorted to the variable increment method.

My code is as follows:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, a.*
FROM a
LIMIT 100;
```

This seems to do what I want, but it is extremely slow. Is there something I am overlooking or is this the reality of the situation?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8, you can use window functions ([Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a1f98/3/0) using Postgres because sqlfiddle only supports 5.6).

Comment: how big is the table that you are using to run this query?

Comment: `0.016` sec for me (with a 3M row table). What is the query plan (`EXPLAIN <query>`)?

Comment: The execution plan should be very simple and fast. Just a Full Table Scan with a limit of 100 rows. What's there to be slow? Actually, how long does it take? What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Please add the execution plan.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, the rows may not be the "first" 100.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE a` -- there may be some clues there.